# Nokia Lumia 625 won't mount in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount, 14.04, nokia

There seem to be several issues around various models of Nokia Lumia not mounting in various flavours of Ubuntu. I don't suppose there's a stock answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with my LG optimus L5. My problem was about some libraries that got broken. To solve this, I runned:

`$ sudo apt-get -f install`

Then, `update`, `upgrade`, `reboot` and it was solved.

Hope this helps.